# How do I use an existing browser window from an email link?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm trying to develop  a Signup/Verify Email process.  The user will

1. Signup from a web-page called /Signup.aspx and enter their email address  (this page tells them to check their email.
2. They will receive a "Verify your email address" email
3. They will click on a link in that email which will send them to /Verified.aspx

This works, however the user ends up with two browsers open.  Ideally when the user clicks on the email link, I'd like for the Verified.aspx page to be opened in the same window that Signup.aspx was in.

I've tried using   but it still opens in different windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. There is no way to reference a specific window from a "page" delivered via email.

The only time a specific window can be referenced is when that window was opened from the same site as the link targeting it.

Comment: I could have sworn I've seen this work before.  What about if the email comes to a web-based email account?